# How to `ls` a remote folder?

Tags: remote, samba, ls

This one uses Samba:

```
 $ ls smb://192.168.5.4/wdtvlivehub/abc
 ls: cannot access smb://192.168.5.4/wdtvlivehub/abc: No such file or directory
```

I somehow managed to do it by;

1. Browsing to the remote directory. (*pcmanfm 0.9.9*)
2. Opening the current folder in a terminal.
3. Executing `pwd` to get `/home/myuser/.gvfs/wdtvlivehub on 192.168.5.4`
4. Doing `ls /home/myuser/.gvfs/wdtvlivehub on 192.168.5.4` worked.

..What would be a more elegant way?

Comment: Is mounting the remote filesystem an option?

Comment: Yep, it can be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current method of using `~/.gvfs/` is fine, but you don't need pcmanfm for that – you can use `gvfs-mount`  to connect to the share. Additionally, tools such as `gvfs-ls` and `gvfs-cp` will accept your *smb://* URI.

```
$ gvfs-mount smb://HOST/SHARE/

$ gvfs-ls smb://HOST/SHARE/
```

In recent gvfs versions the location is `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/` (aka `/run/user/$UID/gvfs/`), and the subdirectory names have become more machine-readable:

```
$ ls /run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb-share:server=HOST,share=SHARE/
```

In older versions:

```
$ ls ~/.gvfs/"SHARE on HOST"/
```

*(Remember to quote spaces within path names.)*

---

Specifically for Samba, you can use the `smbclient` program, or mount the share on the VFS layer by using `mount -t cifs`. (The latter is, unfortunately, limited to root.)

```
$ smbclient //host/share

# mount -t cifs //host/share /mnt
```

(For other kinds of filesystems, such as SFTP and FTP, `sshfs` and `curlftpfs` exist respectively.)

Comment: I mentioned pcmanfm because that is most probably how I will get to the folder before executing it with the script. gv-ls seems to be exactly what I was looking for, though. Looks like it could even replace `ls` for local directories for the sake of consistency.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that "gvfs-ls smb://host/share/" works as described without the need to mount the drive using gvfs-mount first.  In other words, the commands in the first code block don’t all need to be used to achieve your desired outcome.

Comment: @JohnT: Must have been a coincidence. I usually get `The specified location is not mounted`.

Comment: @grawity - I've usually already browsed to the location in Nautilus or similar and authenticated that way, that might have something to do with it.

Comment: @JohnT: Yes, Nautilus uses the same GVFS, and GTK automatically mounts gvfs locations you're trying to access. If the share shows up in Nautilus' side pane, then it is 'mounted' right now.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the command [smbclient](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html), e.g.:

```
smbclient -N //192.168.5.4/wdtvlivehub/abc -c ls
```

Comment: Great, but how can I achieve the same output as with regular `ls` (no columns nor formatting, just a list of files)? It's important because I want to pipe the output to another command.